# Which version of Safari first supported the `<link>` load event?

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, dom-events

Our code requires the `<link>` load event, and we are interested in listing supported Safari versions. Which was the first version of Safari to support the load event on `<link>` for CSS files?

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html appears to refer to a different `load` event.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link lists it as unknown.

http://quirksmode.org/dom/events/load.html is outdated, showing Safari 5.1.

I was unable to find the event at http://caniuse.com. Edit: they have a low priority open ticket to add it at https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/issues/1487

Comment: I feel the vote to close is mistaken - I am not asking for an off-site resource, Instead I have listed my research resources, to prevent duplicated effort. Furthermore, there is a single correct answer; this is not a question that opinion can answer.

Answer (score -1):

Called Apple support, they tested http://www.phpied.com/files/cssonload/test.html on Safari 10 (latest), which fired the DOM's load event (also `onload` event and one of the workaround methods), so at least Safari 10 supports it. This is not a complete answer, but is a useful datapoint (since I was unable to find even that much online).